# Extract selected value from a dropdown in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am trying to write up a simple react application (using react bootstrap) which has a dropdown with some value.

The code for my react component is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { InputGroup, DropdownButton, Dropdown, FormControl, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends Component {
handleSelect = selectedOption => {
    console.log(selectedOption.target);
}

state = {}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Top 3 Expert</h1>
            <hr />
            <Row>
                <Col></Col>
                <Col xs={3}>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <DropdownButton
                            onClick={this.handleSelect}
                            as={InputGroup.Prepend}
                            variant="outline-secondary"
                            title="Choose City"
                            id="input-group-dropdown-1" >
                            <Dropdown.Item href="#">Sydney</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item href="#">Hobart</Dropdown.Item>
                        </DropdownButton>
                        <FormControl aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                    </InputGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col></Col>
            </Row>
        </div >
    );
}
}

export default Header;
```

In my handleSelect method, I am unable to fetch the values 'Sydney' and 'Hobart'.
The output of

```
console.log(selectedOption.target);
```

is

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="button">Sydney</a>
```

Please can you help with understanding how I can extract the selected value from the dropdown.

I have also tried to modify the handler to this

```
handleSelect = selectedOption => {
    console.log(selectedOption.target.value);
}
```

but It prints undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your handler definition to this:-

```
handleSelect = selectedOption => {
    console.log(selectedOption.target.innerText);
}
```

There has to be better option than this though. `react-bootstrap` Dropdown should have some kind of handler where you don't need to play dirty accessing `innerText` like this.

Also your items should be wrapped inside `<Dropdown.Menu></Dropdown.Menu>` and your handler should be present on this instead of the `DropdownButton`.

Comment: I tried doing that but it isn't printing the value. I get undefined.